# Pick random element by percentage weight

Tags: sql-server

Suppose that I have a table format as below, how could I pick a random user based on its percentage with functions/stored procedures in Microsoft SQL Server.

Note that it should be a generic function that cater for any random data in the row.

For normal javascript operation etc, I could find library for this but I couldn't find a built in stored procedure/function in SQL Server for this.

```
user  percentage
-----------------
a     0.1
b     0.3
c     0.4
d     0.2
```

Comment: First get each probability interval for each user (like user a from 0 to 0.1, user b from 0.1 to 0.4, etc.). Then use RAND() to get a value and match against the intervals. You can get the intervals with a rolling sum and a simple rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find each probability interval for each user, then use `RAND()` to find you weighted pick.

```
DECLARE @Random FLOAT = RAND()

;WITH Odds AS
(
    SELECT
        V.*
    FROM
        (VALUES
        ('A', 0.1),
        ('B', 0.3),
        ('C', 0.4),
        ('D', 0.2)
        ) V (UserCode, Percentage)
),
OddIntervals AS
(
    SELECT
        O.*,
        OddStart = SUM(O.Percentage) OVER (ORDER BY O.UserCode) - O.Percentage,
        OddsEnd = SUM(O.Percentage) OVER (ORDER BY O.UserCode)
    FROM
        Odds AS O
)
SELECT
    O.*
FROM
    OddIntervals AS O
WHERE
    @Random > O.OddStart AND
    @Random <= O.OddsEnd
```

`OddsIntervals` looks like the following:

```
UserCode    Percentage  OddStart    OddsEnd
A           0.1         0.0         0.1
B           0.3         0.1         0.4
C           0.4         0.4         0.8
D           0.2         0.8         1.0
```

[RAND()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't return 1, so the last interval might get a little disadvantage.

---

If you need to do this many times, you can use the following script to generate an N amount random numbers (took 4 seconds to generate 100k values for me). You have to provide different seed on each row to get different `RAND()` result so I used `NEWID()` as seed. You can simply replace the #Odds table with yours to execute.

```
DECLARE @AmountRandomValues INT = 100000

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RandomValues') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RandomValues

SELECT TOP (@AmountRandomValues)
    RandomValue = RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY, NEWID()))
INTO 
    #RandomValues
FROM 
    sys.columns AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS s2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Odds') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Odds

CREATE TABLE #Odds (
    UserCode CHAR(1),
    Percentage DECIMAL(3,2))

INSERT INTO #Odds (
    UserCode,
    Percentage)
VALUES
    ('A', 0.1),
    ('B', 0.3),
    ('C', 0.4),
    ('D', 0.2)

;WITH OddIntervals AS
(
    SELECT
        O.*,
        OddStart = SUM(O.Percentage) OVER (ORDER BY O.UserCode) - O.Percentage,
        OddsEnd = SUM(O.Percentage) OVER (ORDER BY O.UserCode)
    FROM
        #Odds AS O
)
SELECT
    R.RandomValue,
    O.*
FROM
    #RandomValues AS R
    INNER JOIN OddIntervals AS O ON 
        R.RandomValue > O.OddStart AND
        R.RandomValue <= O.OddsEnd
```

For 100k values, the amount of user picks for a few runs as example were the following:

First run:

```
UserCode    Amount
A           10222
B           29883
C           39738
D           20157
```

Second run:

```
UserCode    Amount
A           10064
B           29794
C           40061
D           20081
```

Third run:

```
UserCode    Amount
A           10030
B           29960
C           40261
D           19749
```

You can see this is pretty consistent to their odds.

Comment: Would this impact the performance a lot let say like i have 1000 rows

Comment: @vincentsty I've added a solution to generate N random values quickly.

Comment: This part  `SELECT V.* FROM (VALUES
        ('A', 0.1),
        ) V (UserCode, Percentage)` seems to be a hardcoded value, how can i select directly from the table

Comment: @vincentsty i've change the code to use a table. Just replace the #Odds table with yours.